# What is the passphrase used for in ssh key generation?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I was setting up ssh for github and I found it interesting that in addition to a public and private key, a "passphrase" is also needed.

The public/private key pair is generated automatically and the passphrase is asked for after the generation.

[Here is the github documentation.](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).  What is the purpose of this "passphrase".

Does it effect the public and private key generation?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/  <- answers your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not effect the public/private key generation.  It is simply used as an added precaution so that someone who gains access to your PC or similar does not have complete access to all your files.

They will still need a passphrase which is paired with the private key to identify you.

This passphrase can be saved so that you only have to use it once.

Answer (score 2):

The passphrase is used to lock access to the private SSH key. The reason you use keys is to have something more secure than passwords, but a private keyfile without protection will grant access to all your systems to anyone who accesses your computer. So, the passphrase is there to add an extra security layer.